# DIV fill element as vertical

Tags: html, css

i want to fill span as vertical rather it's arrenge as horizontal

```
<div>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </div>

expected result
    1
    2
    3
```

How could i do that?

Comment: The correct answer is probably "Use more appropriate markup" … but your data is too placeholder to say if a set of span elements really is wrong.

Comment: You can use `ul` and put the date like that `<li>1</li>` instead. This will be vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS rule.

```
span {
display:block;
}
```

Spans are inline elements so they'll flow next to each other. By changing them to block elements they'll stack on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `<br />` at the end of each `</span>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to set `display: block`. For example:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    ...
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div#myDiv span {
    display: block;
}
```

Alternatively (and probably more appropriate), just replace the `<span>` elements with divs.

Answer (score 0):

There's three options that I can think of, given the following mark-up:

```
<div id="block">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>

<div id="listItem">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>

<div id="clearLeft">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```

The following CSS *all* (potentially) does what you want:

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

span {
    background-color: #ffa;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

#block span {
    display: block;
}

#listItem {
    display: list; /* just for...(pseudo-semantic) correctness, I guess */
    overflow: visible; /* to show the default list-markers */
}

#listItem span {
    display: list-item;
}

#clearLeft {
    overflow: hidden; /* to wrap the div borders around the
                         floated content */
}

#clearLeft span {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fs8xT/3/).